# in d3js bar chart i want to have fixed bar width

Tags: d3.js

http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8952219

I want to have bar size width to be fixed..

from above example i have changed the code from

```
 svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });
```

to

```
svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("width", 50)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });
```

but the labels are not moving to proper place also bars are getting overlapped

Answer (score 4):

You have to change the `range()` of your `x` scale, to fit with your bar width value:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);
```

to (if you want 50px as bar width)

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().range([0, data.length * 50]);
```

The `range()` method is used to define the display space for your scale.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar solution. What @JulCh gave as an answer did not work out of the box for me, but lead me in the right direction.

Try:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .range(d3.range(data.length).map(function (d) { return d * 50; }));
```

Where the inner `d3.range` creates an array containing the number of elements determined by `data.length` or some `constant` number (the number of bars you would like displayed).

Example: If `data.length` or some `constant is 8` then `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` is returned from `d3.range(8)`

The `map` function then multiplies your fixed width of `50` against each element in the array returning `[0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350].`

D3 will then use these exact values to place your bars.